# How can I select the last element from a list within a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, datatables, jupyter-notebook

First things first, it's been a while so I'm trying to get back into my game.

I'm applying for jobs and wanted to keep track of the jobs I've applied for by scraping it off from indeed. Only, the final bits are still indexed and I wanted to include only what's relevant to the column. I seem to be struggle bussing.

My index for the date I applied looks like this after pulling from the website:
Date_Applied: [[[I applied]], [Today]]

My table ended up looking like the following. You can see the brackets and why I don't want to add, "I applied", "Application Submitted":

```
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+
|                     Position                      |               Company                |             Date_Applied             | Number_of_Applicants |
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Renovation/Construction Underwriter               | Ignite Human Capital | Remote        | [[[I applied]], [Today]]             | [1-10 applicants]    |
| Scientific Computing                              | CG-VAK Softwares USA Inc | Remote    | [[[Application submitted]], [Today]] | [1-10 applicants]    |
| Data Analytics Engineer                           | Delta Defense LLC | West Bend, WI    | [[[I applied]], [Today]]             | [1-10 applicants]    |
| Data Analyst - Tableau - Alteryx - Insurance e... | Grapevine Technology | United States | [[[Application submitted]], [Today]] | [100+ applicants]    |
| Technology Integration Specialist                 | KAGE Innovation | Osceola, WI        | [[[Viewed by employer]], [Today]]    | [1-10 applicants]    |
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

I was hoping there was a way that I can select the last element without removing the first element.
Does anyone have any ideas? Sorry, I may have worded this awkwardly.

My For loop looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = []
for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'atw-AppCard-mainContainer'}):
    job_title = i.find('a', {'class': 'atw-JobInfo-jobTitle'}).text.strip()
    company_name = i.find('div', {'class': 'atw-JobInfo-companyLocation'}).text.strip()  
    number_of_applicants = i.find('span', {'class': 'atw-JobInfo-applicantCount'})
    date= i.find('div', {'class': 'atw-Disposition-value'})

    mytable = {'Position': job_title,
             'Company': company_name,
             'Date_Applied':date,
             'Number_of_Applicants': number_of_applicants}
    data.append(mytable)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the simplest form of the problem along with an example of expected output?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like [split](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split) operator, now as to you can use it before you append to your list as shown-

```
import pandas as pd
data = []
for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'atw-AppCard-mainContainer'}):
    job_title = i.find('a', {'class': 'atw-JobInfo-jobTitle'}).text.strip()
    company_name = i.find('div', {'class': 'atw-JobInfo-companyLocation'}).text.strip()  
    number_of_applicants = i.find('span', {'class': 'atw-JobInfo-applicantCount'})
    date= i.find('div', {'class': 'atw-Disposition-value'})

    mytable = {'Position': job_title,
             'Company': company_name,
             'Date_Applied':date.split(',')[1], # i have changed here.
             'Number_of_Applicants': number_of_applicants}
    data.append(mytable)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Or
If you wish to achieve the same after processing the data then you can perform split on the column-Date_Applied.Reference to this- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html